# Jump instruction in MIPS Assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

Here is some MIPS assembly code I wrote to test the jump instruction:

```
addi $a0, $0, 1
j next
next:
j skip1
add $a0, $a0, $a0
skip1:
j skip2:
add $a0, $a0, $a0
add $a0, $a0, $a0
skip2:
j skip3
loop:
add $a0, $a0, $a0
add $a0, $a0, $a0
add $a0, $a0, $a0
skip3:
j loop
```

When I run the assembler, here's the result:

```
[0x000000]  0x20040001  # addi $a0, $zero, 1 ($a0 = 1)
[0x000004]  0x08000002  # j 0x0002 (jump to addr 0x0008)
[0x000008]  0x08000004  # j 0x0004 (jump to addr 0x0010)
[0x00000C]  0x00842020  # add $a0, $a0, $a0 ($a0 = $a0 + $a0)
[0x000010]  0x08000007  # j 0x0007 (jump to addr 0x001C)
[0x000014]  0x00842020  # add $a0, $a0, $a0 ($a0 = $a0 + $a0)
[0x000018]  0x00842020  # add $a0, $a0, $a0 ($a0 = $a0 + $a0)
[0x00001C]  0x0800000B  # j 0x000B (jump to addr 0x002C)
[0x000020]  0x00842020  # add $a0, $a0, $a0 ($a0 = $a0 + $a0)
[0x000024]  0x00842020  # add $a0, $a0, $a0 ($a0 = $a0 + $a0)
[0x000028]  0x00842020  # add $a0, $a0, $a0 ($a0 = $a0 + $a0)
[0x00002C]  0x08000008  # j 0x0008 (jump to addr 0x0020)
```

Looking at the machine code for the jump instructions, this is what I see:

```
1st jump (just jumps to next instruction) 0x08000002
2nd jump (skips 1 instruction) 0x08000004
3rd jump (skips 2 instructions) 0x08000007
4th jump (skips 3 instructions) 0x0800000B
5th jump (skips 3 instructions backwards) 0x08000008
```

From looking at these instructions, it looks like the machine code starts with a 08 for the jump instruction, and the number at the end tells the jump instruction where to go. However, I can not figure out how this number is calculated. Also, there is nothing to indicate to me that the 5th jump is a backwards jump.

How is the jump value calculated?

Comment: why do you use 3 `add $a0, $a0, $a0`? why don't use `sll $a0, $a0, 3`

Comment: @phuclv let me remind you that you deserve a cookie for this

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just look into a reference manual for more details about the opcode encoding.

Short version: In a 32 bit instruction you can not include a 32-bit jump destination. The opcode uses 6 bits, which leaves 26 bits for the instruction. The target address is constructed by taking the first 4 bits of the address of the instruction following the `j` instruction, then 2 zero bits are appended to the 26 bits from the jump instruction operand. (As the instructions are 32 bits, alignment is useful and allows the omitting of the last two 0's.)

To the backward jump: The addresses are absolute, NOT relative, so it only depends on the address of the jump instruction, whether it is a forward or a backward jump.

**EDIT**: More detailed description:
We have at address *x* jump instruction *j*. Let *t* represent the jump operand of *j*. *t* is 26 bit wide.
The bit pattern of address of the next instruction is computed as follows:

```
upper_6_bits_of(x+4),t,0,0
```

So the jump is **ALWAYS** absolute. There are no relative jumps. when the result is smaller than x then it is a backward jump, when it is greater it is a forward jump (and if you want something stupid, you make it equal ;-).

So let's look at the 5th jump of your example:

The first 6 bits of the jump target are: 000000, because the upper 6 bits of the address of the instruction behind the jump are 000000.

The next 26 bits are the lowest 26 bits of the jump instruction, that is 00000000000000000000001000

The last 2 bits are: 00, because the got always appended.

Together we have: 0000000000000000000000000000100000, which is hex 20. And at that address is exactly the label/instruction where the flow should continue.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about how the relative address is specifying a backwards offset.  Usually, the jmp relative value would be negative to accomplish this.  Also, the offsets above don't make much sense for jumps.  I, like @z-buffer, am also a bit confused by the disassembly...

Comment: Your edit explains the jump as absolute, but the offsets still don't really line up.  There must be something else going on here.  +1 still for answering the complete question.

Comment: @Michael Dorgan: The Backwards jumps is fine as it is: It shows as ...08. That 08 left shifted by two (the two 2 zeros I mentioned) are 32 which is hex 0x20. And the instruction where the jumps goes is 0x..20. So it fits perfectly (same with the other 4 jumps).

Comment: All I understood from your answer was that two bits get added at the end. Could you explain in a more mathematical way and show how it works in this case? Also it's not clear from your explanation whether forward jump addresses are relative or not.

Comment: Ah jeez, I was counting labels as op-codes when I did my instruction counting.  Makes perfect sense now.  Thanks.

Comment: @flolo, for ease of understanding, the value in the jump statement is the number of instructions from the beginning of your executable (base 0).  The  first jump has ...02, so it goes to the 3rd op-code.  The next ends in 4 so it goes to the 5th op-code, and so forth for each jump.  The part about the high bits only matters when doing very, very long jumps and when data steps across memory boundaries - something you won't need to worry about for a while.

Comment: So in other words, the number in the jump instruction is simply the hex value of the the destination address in binary shifted right by 2 bits.

Comment: @z-buffer: yes (besides the 6 topmost bits).

Comment: @flolo `upper_6_bits_of(x+4)` Why are the upper __6__ bits taken? Shouldn't it be the upper __4__ bits? Because from my understanding, upper 6 bits + 26 bits from instruction + 2 bits shift makes 34, not 32.

Comment: @alxnull I agree with this. The reference sheet I'm using specifies the upper 4 bits of PC + 4, then 26 operand bits, then 00.

Answer (score 8):

In MIPS, `J` is a J-type instruction:

```
J-type instructions (Jumps)
3    22
1    65                        0
+----+-------------------------+
| op |         target          |
+----+-------------------------+
```

So we have a `target` that is 26-bits long. It gets combined with the PC of the next instruction as follows:

```
I
I+1 PC <- (PC & 0xf0000000) | (target << 2)
```

It is shifted left 2 bits, since MIPS instructions (ignoring the MIPS16 extension) are 32-bits long, meaning they all start in an address whose lower 2 bits are zero.

Comment: Another way to think of it is, what's the smallest nonzero value you can put into a jump instruction? That would be a 1, and it corresponds to the 2nd instruction in the program, which is at 0x4. So basically it's a jump to the absolute address of the instruction, divided by 4, since the addresses are nth instruction is always (n-1)*4. To divide by 4, you shift right by 2 bits because shifting right n bits divides a number by (2^n).