# How far can the j(jump) instruction jump in memory? (MIPS)

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

Consider the j(jump) instruction in MIPS. How far can it jump in memory? Would it be 32bits? Can i please have an explanation.

Comment: There isn't really anything to try. I am studying for a test. I just want to know how far that instruction can jump.

Comment: Ya, i have seen 26, 32, and 4 bits. SO i am just confused now.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877407/jump-instruction-in-mips-assembly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20120107030450/http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html), you'll see that the jump instruction has the following effects:

```
PC = nPC; nPC = (PC & 0xf0000000) | (target << 2);
```

`target` is a 26 bit number.  That means the `j` instruction can jump to any absolute address that can be created from the operation above.  The largest value for `target`, therefore, is 2<sup>26</sup>-1 (0x03FFFFFF), and the highest reachable address is `(PC & 0xF0000000) | 0x0FFFFFFC`.

Comment: similar discussion [Range of MIPS j instruction](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/162976/range-of-mips-j-instruction)

Comment: link is dead, try the archived version - https://web.archive.org/web/20120107030450/http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html

Comment: Another way to say this is that `j` is region-absolute, in the region containing the instruction *after* the `j` itself (the branch-delay slot).  Notice the `PC = nPC` statement before keeping the high 4 bits of PC; you omitted that from later discussion but still used PC instead of next_PC.  That PC+=4 can propagate carry into the high 4 bits at the end of a 256MB region.

Comment: I always find it unclear to just write "PC" for a single instruction, whether that's the instruction address, or already incremented before decode.  I'd have written `((J_addr+4) & 0xf0000000) | target << 2`.  e.g. in [How to Calculate Jump Target Address and Branch Target Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6950230) it requires multiple paragraphs of text to clarify those diagrams that use `PC`.  (Especially because the diagrams are sloppy re: the corner case where the delay slot is in a different region than the `j`.)