# Finding the jump address of an instruction

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to find the jump address for the following instruction:

Instruction 'j' is at address: PC = 11000000 01010101 11111111 00001100

How would I go about finding the jump address?

Comment: Not from PC. We'd need to know the instruction that is there.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877407/jump-instruction-in-mips-assembly