# MIPS jump to label, and PC increment

Tags: mips

I have the following MIPS assembly code

```
        loop: add $t1,$t1,$t1
              j   loop
```

and I know that loop is located at 0x1FFF FFF8

now, I am not certain that the program will work okay...
when jump is excecuted - the PC address is 0x2000 0000 or 0x1FFF FFFC ?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

nevermind, found the answer here
[Jump instruction in MIPS Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877407/jump-instruction-in-mips-assembly)

the JUMP is calculated with the 4bits of the next PC address (like an offset in a beq command)